# Android. Is apk installation in progress?

Tags: android

my application has to reinstall itself. I manage to do so. However, I have a problem that I can not resolve.

**Installation pop-up is closing when user taps somewhere beyond installation pop-up and installation is still in progress. The problem is that user can work with application for some time, until application suddenly closes because installation has finished. I'd like to somehow avoid such situation.**

So, the main question is how can I detect if there is installation in progress?

To make things harder application is written in Qt and device can not be rooted.

Here is a piece of code I use to install application.

```
public static void installApk( Context context )
{
    File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/myApk.apk" );
    Uri fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile( context, context.getPackageName() + ".provider", file );
    Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri );
    intent.putExtra( Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true );
    intent.setDataAndType( fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive" );
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
    intent.addFlags( Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION );
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: You should probably close your app after starting the installation intent and then restart it when you receive `ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`.

Comment: Close my app? Do you mean adding `finish() ` after `context.startActivity(intent);`?
I'm not really convinced to this solution, but thank you anyway for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Installing an APK means uninstall your application and install it again that's why your application closes. You can not prevent this behavior

Comment: if you try to install the apk from browser then after install button click, appear horizontal progress bar. After install success, two button appear, open and done. Is it not possible in own app update from new version installation?